# Navbar is hidding titles when opened from links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a navbar that follows the scroll of the user. The situation I need to solve is that I have a footer with links of the topics of a page. This footer is global in my website.
[image: Site Description]

I'm already anchoring the titles with IDs and it is working. The problem is that when I open it in another tab by those links in the footer, the navbar is positioned exactly in front of the titles(and this is bad). 
Is there a way that I can control how much the anchor is positioned when it is loaded from another page?
Here is the part of the code of the footer where the links used are:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><h4>>Links<li>
        <li><a href="{{url('page#tag1')}}">Tag1</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{url('page#tag2')}}">Tag2</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{url('page#tag3')}}">Tag3</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{url('page#tag4')}}">Tag4</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{url('page#tag5')}}">Tag5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a padding-top on the titles. This padding-top must have the same height as your navbar.